# Automatically create new .mdf file on different hard drive when database is full

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-administration

Is it possible to **automatically** create a new `.mdf` file for a database on a different hard drive when the drive is almost full?

We have a limitation of 500GB per drive so whenever a database file reaches the hard drive limit I want SQL Server to create an extra `.mdf` file on a different drive so it won't run out of disk space.

I have seen a lot of alert systems that issue a warning when you need to do it manually, but I don't know if it can be done automatically with a SQL script.

Comment: A new mdf file would be a brand-new, empty, database. SQL Server does not support "spanning" databases over multiple MDF files.

Comment: Hello Dai. Thanks for answering. With a new .mdf file i mean an expantion with an extra .mdf on a different harddrive.

Comment: I understood you correctly then - SQL Server does not support expanding, sharding, or otherwise spanning a database over multiple MDF files.